# Adding a package to dojo config at runtime

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way I can add a new package to dojo config? I know I can do this: Add packages when dojo.js loads.

```
<script src='dojo_1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js' 
    data-dojo-config="async:true,isDebug:true,parseOnLoad:false,
      packages:[{name:'project1',location:'../../js/proj1'},
        {name:'common',location:'../../common'}]"></script>
```

I want to be able to add new packages at runtime.

**dojo.registerModulePath** did do this job prior to dojo1.6 (i think) but its now deprecated in 1.7

I am using dojo 1.7.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add extra packages after load by calling require with a config object.

```
Eg:

require({
    packages: [
        {"name": "myLib", "location": "release/myLib"}
    ]
});
```

This will however, create another instance of Dojo, according to the documentation ([dojo/_base/config](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/_base/config)).  Also, this is version **1.8** code; I don't think it works with **1.7**.

I thought it might  possible to push an extra object to *dojoConfig* or *require.rawConfig* but these are not picked-up by the loader.  It appears that config cannot be changed after load.

You can pass a config object to require, so:

```
Eg.

dojoConfig.packages.push({"name": "myLib", "location": "release/myLib"});

require(dojoConfig, [...moduleIds...], function(...arguments...) {
});
```

This will work for the individual require but will not modify the global config (and hence will not work in **define()** or subsequent calls to **require()**). Again, I'm using **1.8** here but I assume it works in **1.7**.

There may be another simpler way of making this work that someone else as found?

Comment: Thanks Stephen! 
dojoConfig.packages.push({"name": "myLib", "location": "release/myLib"}); worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Stephen Simpson didn't seem to work right for me with dojo v1.13. It ignored the given location and was still trying to load the files relative to the default `basePath` despite of the project path starting it with a `/`. I got errors in the console, too.

But [the documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/config.html#finding-resources-in-non-standard-locations) also mentions the `paths` parameter which worked for me. In your case:

```
require({paths:{"project1": "../../js/proj1", …}});
```

It probably worked for you because you're using a relative path and I don't.

It used to be `dojo.registerModulePath("myModule", "/path/goes/here");`.